pgadmin 4 timeout connection expired
There is no problem with my pgadmin4 but when I open after a day I can't connect/access the database. I don't know what happened to it. I am using pgadmin4 in win10. connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: timeout expired connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: timeout expired
I tried to search it online and I never found a solution that's why I tried to post it here.
